# How to get NO_DATA_FOUND exception to output when using COUNT(*)?

Tags: sql, oracle, exception, plsql

I am trying to determine why my exception output is not returning correctly.

This is for Oracle SQL Developer, practicing with PL/SQL. I can provide the table code if requested.

```
SET serveroutput on

CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure GetPermissions(user IN VARCHAR, docNum OUT 
INTEGER)
IS
BEGIN
SELECT count(*) INTO docNum FROM UserPermissions where UserName=user;

EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
dbms_output.put_line('Nothing found for this username');
END;
/

DECLARE
doc_count INTEGER;
BEGIN
 doc_count:=0;
 GetPermissions('Steve', doc_count);
 dbms_output.put_line(' Number of documents: ' || doc_count);
END;
/
```

I am expecting the exception to return its output (nothing found) when 'Steve' is ran through as that is not a username in the table I created. When running currently is just shows "Number of documents: 0".

Answer (score 5):

`COUNT` always returns a result, in this case, it returns a single row with 0 in it:

```
COUNT(*)
--------
0
```

`NO_DATA_FOUND` occurs only when the `SELECT INTO` query doesn't return any row.

For example, `NO_DATA_FOUND` will be thrown, if you try to select permission for a given user:

```
SELECT permission 
INTO p_permission
FROM UserPermissions 
WHERE UserName=user;
```

In this case, the query will return an empty result.

Comment: ... or it will return TOO-MANY-ROWS if *Steve* has several permissions :)

Comment: @Littlefoot or it will complete normally if *Steve* has exactly one :) I only know that he had 0 permissions at some point in time, but with *Steve* you can never be sure.

Comment: Huh, right ... I forgot that query might actually return *something* :)

Answer (score 0):

select into query returns with No_Data_found exception when the out put of the query is no rows. not when it is 0.

Another exception  you get with select into clause is too many rows where the query returns more that 1 row and you are trying to assign all those to a variable.